# Variable that automatically updates when another property is updated

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, oop

I'm sure this is a very simple thing and there's just something I fundamentally don't understand about properties/variables. I want the class to have a variable that is assigned/calculated after some property values are input. This isn't homework, I'm just using a simplified example.

```
Public Class person

    Public Property name As String
    Public Property address As String
    Public phoneNumber As String

    Public Sub getPhoneNumber()
        phoneNumber = lookLookThemUpInThePhoneBook
    End Sub

End Class
```

I might not know the person's name AND address when they are created, but as soon as they are both assigned, I want the phone number to be calculated.

I know I could just do

```
Dim Eddy As New person

Eddy.name = "Ed Wood"
Eddy.address = "123 Sample Road"
Eddy.getPhoneNumber()

Debug.Print(Eddy.phoneNumber)
```

But this will get very cumbersome having to manually run the procedure, so I figure there has to be a way to have that value get proactively assigned.

I'd like to be able to do this

```
Eddy.name = "Ed Wood"
Eddy.address = "123 Sample Road"
Debug.Print(Eddy.phoneNumber) ' His phone number is just automatically looked up.
```

Comment: You can include logic in the property setter...the property would typically be ReadOnly so that it cant be set other than by your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delay the phone number lookup until the phoneNumber property is referenced by implementing that logic in the setter of that property (as mentioned in the comments).  Here is an example of that:

```
Public ReadOnly Property phoneNumber As String
    Get
        'Leverage a class level private variable and wrap in an
        'If Statement if you only want To look it up once.
        Return lookLookThemUpInThePhoneBook()
    End Get
End Property
```

Then when you do `objYourPerson.phoneNumber` it does the look up for you.

Answer (score 1):

Both the Name and Address properties can try to set the phone number when they are modified

```
Public Class Person
    Private _name As String = ""
    Private _address As String = ""
    Private _phoneNumber As String = "not set yet..."
    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _name = value
            setPhoneNumber()
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Address As String
        Get
            Return _address
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _address = value
            setPhoneNumber()
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property PhoneNumber As String
        Get
            Return _phoneNumber
        End Get
        Private Set(value As String)
            _phoneNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub setPhoneNumber()
        If Name <> "" AndAlso Address <> "" Then PhoneNumber = lookThemUpInThePhoneBook(Name, Address)
    End Sub
    Private Function lookThemUpInThePhoneBook(name As String, address As String) As String
        Return "123456789" ' search by name and address here
    End Function
End Class
```

usage:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Eddy As New Person()
    Eddy.Name = "Ed Wood"
    Console.WriteLine(Eddy.PhoneNumber)
    Eddy.Address = "123 Sample Road"
    Console.WriteLine(Eddy.PhoneNumber)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

output

> not set yet...
>   
>  123456789

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```
Public Class Person
    Public Sub New(strname As String, straddress As String)
         name = strname
         address = straddress
         _phoneNumber = LookThemUpInThePhoneBook(strname, straddress)
    End Sub

    Private Function LookThemUpInThePhoneBook(pName As String, pAddress As String) As String
        Dim myPhone As String = ""
        'Do work to look up phone number
        Return myPhone
    End Function

    Private _phoneNumber As String
    Public ReadOnly Property phoneNumber As String
        Get
            Return _phoneNumber
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _name As String
    Public Property name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _address As String
    Public Property address As String
        Get
            Return _address
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _address = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Then

```
Dim Eddy As New Person("Eddy wood", "123 Sample Road")
Debug.Print(Eddy.phoneNumber)
```